# Каким способом ещё можно решить данную задачу по sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Структура базы данных: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a2a429/3
Таблица `s` - поставщики
`p` - товары, поставляемые поставщиками
`sp` - поставки товаров
Стоит задача:
**Определить номера поставщиков, поставляющих, по меньшей
мере, все детали, поставляемые поставщиком 2 (Jones)**
Решил эту задачу так:

```
select * from sp 
join s on s.s=sp.s
where sp.s<>2
and sp.p in (select sp.p from sp where sp.s=2)
group by sp.s 
having count(*)=(select count(*) from sp where sp.s=2)
```

меня интересует то, что это выражение `(select sp.p from sp where sp.s=2)` вызывается дважды.
Правильно ли я решил данную задачу, или есть более правильное решение?

Comment: *это выражение `(select sp.p from sp where sp.s=2)` вызывается дважды* - это называется "невнимательность".

Comment: @Akina, можете показать правильное решение?

Comment: ведь по сути 1) нужно определить те товары, которые поставляет Jones,2) и определить количество этих товаров

Comment: @Akina что не так с вопросом, почему поставили минус?

Comment: `select sp.p` и `select count(*)` две большие разницы. Ничего у вас дважды не вызывается. Можно ли сделать запрос по-другому? Возможно. Но на это ответит, скорее всего, только Mike

Comment: @ArchDemon, что значит "Но на это ответит, скорее всего, только Mike" ?

Comment: У нас есть мега-специалист по sql запросам. Обычно он отвечает на такие вопросы

Comment: @word Не знаю, спросите того, кто поставил минус. PS. Но вообще-то меня это не удивляет.

Answer (score 1):

Можно так(использовался [трюк](https://qna.habr.com/q/15730) с `join`, с помощью которого определялось, является ли одно множество подмножеством другого):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    s as seller
WHERE
    seller.s != 2
AND
    (not exists(
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            (SELECT
                p as id
            FROM
                sp
            WHERE
                s = 2
            ) as _subset
        LEFT JOIN
            (SELECT
                p as id
            FROM
                sp
            WHERE
                seller.s = sp.s
          ) as _set
        ON
            _subset.id = _set.id
        WHERE
            _set.id is NULL)
OR
    not exists(
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            sp
        WHERE
            sp.s = 2));
```

Comment: вы проверяли свой пример здесь? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a2a429/3
ваш код не работает

Comment: @word я проверил его в среде mysql

Comment: Странно, в онлайн компиляторах не работает, а у меня на машине работает

Comment: @word Говорят(https://forums.oscommerce.com/topic/230304-1054-unknown-column-pproducts_id-in-on-clause/), что это проблема конкретно mysql5. Попробуйте подать этот запрос на сервер высшей версии(онлайн-"компиляторов" не нашел)

Comment: а можете поправить для 10.3.13-MariaDB ?
 в openserver также не работает

Comment: @word К сожалению, я только запросы составлять умею. На чистом MySQL версии 8.0.18 проверял работоспособность. Вот еще об этой проблеме(https://forum.php-myadmin.ru/viewtopic.php?id=256) и еще(https://www.zen-cart.com/showthread.php?37460-1054-Unknown-column-p-products_id-in-on-clause)(здесь конкретное решение проблемы)